# Could not find default endpoint element that references contract

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, web-services, c#-4.0

I have created a WCF web service, i am calling it from ASP.NET 1.1 website.

I have added a simple operation contract to send a string value = IT WORKED.

***Information on WCF Web service***

> > I have added one DLL in the WCF web service.
> >     I am accessing the DLL's exposed methods in the operation contract.

*But i am facing an issue when i am invoking the operation contract :*

In the web service i have referenced/added a DLL which is exposing some methods,
    and i am calling those methods in my one operation contract.
    **description7a.Description7aPortType = this is coming from 
    the DLL i have added in the WCF service.**

It is giving error :

```
   Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
    'description7a.Description7aPortType' in the ServiceModel client 
    configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was
    found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this 
    contract could be found in the client element.
```

How can i fix this?

WEB CONFIG OF WCF Web service

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ADSChromeVINDecoder.Service" behaviorConfiguration="asmx">
        <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                contract="ADSChromeVINDecoder.IService"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="asmx">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: The referenced DLL seems to be using another WCF Service and is expecting the endpoint configuration in the web.config file. Check the documentation of the referenced DLL and the requirements of how to use the functionality provided by the DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a service reference of the web service used by the DLL did the endpoint setting itself.